# How to get list of account that are changed in given time frame

Tags: universe

We are planning to export data from universe and load them into sql(mirroring). But it will be great if we can load only the accounts that are changed.

Comment: Send an email to U2AskUs@rs.com if you want to get in touch with people who can help you do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UniVerse offers 2 technologies that can do this for you, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Talk to your support provider about Replication with EDA.

EDA stands for 'External Database Access'. It is a built-in technology that will automatically send any record updates to a foreign database, such as Server SQL , DB2 or Oracle.

EDA by itself will convert your local UniVerse tables to remote SQL tables. Most people won't want this, they will still want UniVerse tables locally (for performance reasons). You can use Replication (or Single Server Replication) to achieve the best of both worlds.

You can read the [EDA manual](http://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKB14/universe/11.2/eda.pdf) on Rocket's site.

Note, you will need to be on the latest version of UniVerse. Luckily, UniVerse is highly backwards compatible and Rocket's support are professional service teams are experienced in this.